# Is there any functions to extract the combinations of sets

Tags: probability-or-statistics, permutation

Suppose I have a function f which is depending on a,b,c (f[a_,b_,c_]). these a, b, c can take two value zero and infinity. How to have a combination of the function f when it takes zero and infinity values. how many such combinations are possible? Is there any built-in function to carry out this in Mathematica. Actually, the number of variables will increase so I am looking for any built of function exist to carry out this.

Comment: Have a look at `Tuples`.

Comment: Since there are two choices for each of three parameters, there are `2^3` possible parameter settings. More generally, for `n` choices with `m` parameters, there are `n^m` possible parameter settings.

Comment: yes, you are correct. but my question was is there any built-in function in Mathematica for doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tuples` gives you the combination of elements, in your case `Tuples[{0, ∞}, 3]`.

> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, ∞}, {0, ∞, 
>     0}, {0, ∞, ∞}, {∞, 0, 
>     0}, {∞, 0, ∞}, {∞, ∞, 
>     0}, {∞, ∞, ∞}}

Since that returns a matrix, you can evaluate your function if you put the variables in brackets and use `Map`. A tractable example where instead of inf I use 1.

```
f[{a_, b_, c_}] := a + b + c
f /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, 3]
```

> {0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3}

Comment: It solves my problem thanks. Tuples function is very helpful while handling combinations.

Comment: Or with the original form for `f` use [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html): `f[a_, b_, c_] := a + b + c; f @@@ Tuples[{0, 1}, 3]`